# Solving $\int_{a}^{b} f'(x)|f(x)|^sdx$ for $s\neq -1$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $s\neq -1$. Solve the integral $$\int_{a}^{b} f'(x)|f(x)|^sdx$$

I would like to ask for hints on how to get started.

Comment: If $f$ were positive (so the $s$th power were defined) and there were no absolute value, would you be able to proceed?

Comment: Yes, I would then use partial integration. Do I have to consider both cases, where it is positive and negative?

Comment: Formally, if $g(x) = \frac{|f(x)|^{s+1}}{s+1}$, the chain rule gives $$g'(x) = |f(x)|^{s} \frac{f(x)}{|f(x)|}\, f'(x) = |f(x)|^{s-1} f(x)\, f'(x)$$at points where $f(x) \neq 0$. Particularly, the integral is improper if $s < 0$, and you can't generally expect convergence if $s < -1$ (though convergence does depend on $f$). If your $f$ has only finitely many zeros, you can break up the interval according to the sign of $f$. If you're looking for a general formula (i.e., for arbitrary differentiable $f$ for which the integral converges), I don't think there's simple expression.

Answer (score 1):

Try it changing the variable from $x$ to $y = f(x)$. It will give you an integral of $|y|^s$. Then, you just have to pay attention to the sign of $y$ between the limits of the new integral $\left(f(a)\right.$ and $\left.f(b)\right)$. Say it if you want it more explicit.